# Excel vba : Help for Grid lines

Tags: excel, vba

I have details from Column A to column M in Sheet 1.

I need to implement Grid lines for the same from Column A to M.

The complication part is, there are 3 different tables in sheet 1 wherein i need to implement Grid lines separately for all those 3 tables based on Used range.

I have macro for the same but it is just working by implementing grid lines altogether for 3 tables. Refer the screenshot for output.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vazb.png)

Comment: It would help if you broke this into a couple sentences as part of a more thorough explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

standing your data layout example, you could also use `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object

```
Dim area As Range

For Each area In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
    With area.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response but it dosen't show my tables with gridlines.

Comment: Then your tables are not fill with data as you showed them in your screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Use the [range.CurrentRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion) property to isolate each data block.

```
dim i as long

with worksheets("sheet1")

    if isempty(.cells(1, "A")) then
        i = .cells(1, "A").end(xldown).row
    else
        i = 1
    end if

    do while i < .rows.count

        with .cells(i, "A").currentregion
            'do the border formatting here
            'example:
            With .Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Color = vbRed
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With

            debug.print .address(0, 0)
        end with

        i = .cells(i, "A").end(xldown).end(xldown).row

    loop

end with
```

Comment: This works great.. but how to add autofit along with gridlines.. I have added Selection.autofit but it dosen't work..

Comment: That would seem like a new question as it is too complicated to get into within the comments section.

Comment: Does it mean, it is not possible to include autofit ? :)